# Connect notebook HDD using USB kit

Tags: hard-drive, sata-to-usb

I am currently trying to connect the 2.5" SATA drive of my broken notebook to my desktop computer. I have a USB kit that has cables that seem to fit (data cable and power supply). However, on the HDD it says 1A and DC +5V, but on the power supply adapter of the USB kit it says that the output is: 12V --- 1500mA and below: 5V --- 1500mA. So I am not sure if I should use this power supply? I really don't wsnt to break it as I have lots of data on the harddisk that I'd like to recover... I found many different opinions in the web on this and therefore am still unsure. Could you please explain me why this is safe or why not?

Here are some pictures of the harddisk and the power supply adapter and how I would connect them:

2.5" HDD:
[image]

Power supply adapter: 
[image]

Unfortunately I can't post a third link yet. Its the sameas the previous one but with image code x276l2.jpg
Woukd be great if someone could maybe post it to the comments!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the adapter comes with the adapter it should be safe, the kit is designed for both desktop and laptop hdd, and desktop HDD draws power mostly from 12V so there is a 12V output for the adapter. And you wouldn't get 12V on the 5V input if the power supply works properly.

However, I suggest you to just hook the laptop HDD to desktop directly, if the desktop has spare SATA power plug and SATA cable available, you can plugin and use the laptop hdd just like a normal desktop HDD, in this way its faster and usually more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested it first directly using the desktop's internal cables and as this did not work, I used the kit to connect the HDD via USB. Unfortunately, there is no life sign at all. Even when I listen close to the HDD, I can't hear a noise. Is this possible or even normal for a 2.5" HDD? Or is it definitely dead?